# SP_FAdmin given "Full Control", but when check permissions, it shows as "None"

Tags: permissions

In one of my sites, I stopped "Inherit permission" from the root site, it has its own set of permissions.

The "SP_FAdmin" (SharePoint Farm Admin) account is given "Full Control" directly to the site root level. but when I perform "Check Permissions" against this account, I see:

> ```
> Permission levels given to SP_FAdmin
> none
> The following factors also affect the level of access for SP_FAdmin
> Allow Manage Permissions
> ```

One of the server side applications need to run under this "SP_Fadmin" account, currently the program won't run because the admin account doesnt' have access to this site.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to add the SP_FAdmin account into Policy of Web Application...directly from central admin > appliation management >manage web applications > user policy from ribbon....now add the user with full control.

Comment: Hi, Waqas, Thanks for your reply, this account "SP_FAdmin" is already in the web policy. The account was added to the web policy when the farm was built. Is "Broken permission inheritance" the issue? Should I "Inherit from Parent" again?

Comment: if it is full control in the policy for webapp...so break inheritance will not effect this id...but it is sharepoint you can try re inherit the permission and try again. also try to add that account as site collection admin.

Comment: Hi, Waqas, I re inherit the permission from parent site again, but everytime I grant "SP_FAdmin" "Full Control" access, the page shows ok, but when I perform "Check Permissions" against this account "SP_FAdmin", I'm getting 
"Permission Level given to SP_Admin" 
Limited Access Given directly, and my program still errors out.